# SVN whitespace in folder results in file not found %2520

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, mod-dav-svn

We use CentOS 7 and have the newest version of apache and svn in the repositories:

`Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)`

`svnadmin, version 1.7.14 (r1542130)`

When adding a Folder to a repository on the server with a blank in the name ("test folder") the folder is added. But as soon as I try to add a file inside the folder I get the error:
`File not found: transaction '2086-1p6', path '/test%20folder/test.txt'`
On the client side I tested it with commandline svn tools and TortoiseSVN (Version 1.9.2).
When inspecting the commit with wireshark I can see that the blank in the path is encoded twice (to %2520) on the PUT:
`PUT /svn/repos/IT/!svn/wrk/5bd09f52-ff13-0c4a-822e-cc29d91498ba/test%2520folder/test.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n`
In Folders with no whitespace the commit works perfectly, even when files have a whitespace in the name.
I found the following suggestion to fix the problem:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/+bug/1285204

But I'd like to refrain from manually compiling and installing SVN from source since we'd like to stay on the version officially shipped with CentOS.

I hope I  included every needed information in this post, if not please let me know and I'll add whats necessary.

Comment: svn version 1.7.14 is definitely *not* the newest version. In fact it's two (2) major versions behind. Not just minor versions but two major versions!

Comment: It is however unfortunately the current version that is **available in the Centos repositories** and I don't have the option to install from source.